# How to get the document in the callback of Mongoose/MongoDB update all

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I had to change this

```
        User.findOneAndUpdate({
            _id: new ObjectId(item.user)
        }, {
            $inc: {
                code: 1
            }
        }).exec(function (err, companyOwner) {
           console.log(companyOwner); // ta-da! I get the document
        });
```

to this because I want to update multiple documents.

```
User.update({
            _id: new ObjectId(item.user)
        }, {
            $inc: {
                code: 1
            }
        }, {multi: true}, function (err, companyOwner){
            console.log('The company owner is', companyOwner); // The company owner is { ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 }
});
```

The problem is companyOwner in the callback now looks like this instead of the document

Comment: Even in the second code you are updating only one item, because you are identifying the object by `_id`

Comment: Doh! Thanks for pointing that out :)